# Facebook Send a Gift API

Tags: facebook, api

can someone direct me on this,

I want to make an app that essentially allows a user to select a 'gift' - (just a static image of my choice), Select a friend and hit post..

Basically similar to this Coca Cola example : http://www.facebook.com/home.php#!/cocacola?sk=app_157721657609068

What should I need to look for api wise? Completely new to this, appreciate any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People like Coca Cola achieve that effect using the [Buddy Media platform](http://www.buddymedia.com/platform/features). If you look at the source code for the app you will see that they are faking the Facebook popup box by generating it using a modal window - the rest is then tied together using [FBML requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/#notifications-and-requests).